# I am trying to give upper case but it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery data I am trying to convert in upper case but it not work.

```
$('#lr_from').val(data.bilty[0].lr_from).toUpperCase();
```

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4">From</label>
                    <!-- <div class="form-group " class="form-control" > -->
                    <select class="form-control col-md-8" name="lr_from" id="lr_from"  disabled>
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" id="lr_from_id" name="lr_from_id" > 
                    <!--  </div> -->
                  </div>

$.ajax({
            url  : "<?php echo base_url();?>enquiry/EnquiryController/getBiltyNo",
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                 lr_no :lr_no  
                },

           success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

            $('#lr_from').val(data.bilty[0].lr_from).toUpperCase();
        },
   });
```

Comment: can you post what you are getting?

Comment: Try `$('#lr_from').val(data.bilty[0].lr_from.toUpperCase());`

Comment: @User863 not working

Comment: @RayA I uploaded my selection code

Comment: @farhantechno `console error` message can help you better than `not working` message

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, and you are trying to upper case the values of the select list? what is your console output, give us example of the actual output and the  ajax output as well.

Comment: The `toUpperCase` is a JS method does not change the original string. It returns a value. Solution provided by @User863 should work.

Comment: @User863 as per above image I want to show `pune` as `PUNE` and my console there is no error

Comment: @user1309690 In my `from` value is in lowwer case just I want to show upper case my value

Comment: its a logical error dude, `toUpperCase` returns capital string, so you have to store that string in variable and then set the uppercase string to your desired input using : e.g.`$('#lr_from').val(stored_str_var)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) instead of `val()`

```js
$('#lr_from option').text(function() {
  return $(this).text().toUpperCase()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="lr_from">
  <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
</select>
```